# Craft or Twig converting html tags to alt characters

Tags: craft3, twigextension

Just starting with plugin development. I modified the code from pluginfactory.io for a custom tag:

```
public function navHTML()
{
    $result = '<h2>Hello again</h2>';
    return $result;
}
```

and I am getting output. The issue is the html tags are being converted to alt characters. Here is the actual source of my index page:

```
&lt;h2&gt;Testing&lt;/h2&gt;
```

IT looks like Craft or Twig is converting the tags to alt characters. I need to create an unordered list html using the plugin. How do I prevent Craft or Twig from converting the HTML to alt characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that you're returning the `raw` version of the HTML.

In Craft 2, it looks like this...

```php
return TemplateHelper::getRaw($result);
```

In Craft 3, it looks like this...

```php
return Template::raw($result);
```

If you're doing this in Craft 3, you need to also be sure that you are loading the `Template` helper class at the top:

```php
use craft\helpers\Template;
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting: you can also use/access that function inside your template with `{{ html|raw }}`